# Change window.location.ancestorOrigins

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, browser

Is there any way to change or block the usage of `window.location.ancestorOrigins` in iframed sites under Chrome?

For security reasons, I do not wish the iframed page to be able to detect the top url.

Under Firefox, if the `<iframe>` is pointing to another `<iframe>`, it solves the issue.
But under Chrome, it's still detecting the main website.

Comment: What is a 'security reason' for preventing something you embed on your site from knowing where it's being embedded? I see changing the contents of this array as a security issue, so I'm curious to know your intent.

Comment: @Seanonymous it's equivalent to providing a website with your local IP, name, address, as you're the one accessing the site. embed a site and it knows where you come from? sounds bad to me

Answer (score 3):

No. And the discussion is going on since 2016! https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1918

This is what you get when google advertising money funds Chrome development.

Also note that on chrome you can override document.referrer via defineProperty(), but not window.location.ancestorOrigins. They really care about that property, just not enough to respect the content security policies on it  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

@seanonymous (new account, can't reply to comments here yet) the usecase is that some sites expose information in the URL that they do not want partners to see. For example, CNN might leverage google or facebook for login information. They are fine sharing with those companies that the user is reading cnn.com in exchange for the authorization flow to their comment section. But they might not be ok sharing the article the user wishes to comment on to those companies. This problem has been solved a decade ago by W3c via CSP and referrer control headers. But google implemented this without anybody's comment, just like microsoft did during their IE4~6 market dominance.

Comment: yea this is terrible, completely disregarding request headers and effectively tracking a users history

Comment: `But they might not be ok sharing the article the user wishes to comment on to those companies.` I'm confused how this is related to window.location.ancestorOrigins - doesn't that property only give the iframe the _origins_ of the ancestor frames? How does that reveal the specific article?

Comment: @drmercer Most implementations for this hook up on referrer polices, which can be more restrictive or more lax with some combinations. A site might be leaking full path via location.ancestorOrigins and the owner might not even be aware, because they relaxed referrer to get more info on something else they expect to be unrelated to run-time code. But for the happy-path, you are right, it should only expose the origin (schema + domain), sadly, real world is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple : You just can not change it.