# Retrieve URL of AppScript using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-apps-script

I am trying to reload the current page with a new parameter, but I am unable to retrieve the correct URL of the webpage. I am getting an alternate URL instead of the one that triggers the web app

```
https://script.google.com/a/user/macros/s/A...ljhGC/dev?action=menu&id=1
```

when the button is clicked I want the action parameter's value to change and the  page to reload as

```
https://script.google.com/a/user/macros/s/A...ljhGC/dev?action=checkout&id=1
```

Here is my javascript within the HTML File

```
console.log(document.url);

      var url = new URL(window.location.href);
      var query_string = url.search;
      var search_params = new URLSearchParams(query_string); 
      search_params.set('action', 'checkout');
       url.search = search_params.toString();
       var new_url = url.toString();
       window.location.replace(new_url);
       console.log(new_url);
    }
```

This is the URL that gets logged

```
https://n-ikwx...khq-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel?action=checkout
```

How do I retrieve the actual URL that is in the address bar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue:

A iframe with different origin cannot read the *href* property of location of the the parent/top frame, which is write only. So, You can't(However, In chrome/chromium, [`location.ancestorOrigins` is  provided, mainly so that advertisers can read the `top` origin, as chrome is message
made by a advertising company with conflict of interests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873384))

#### Solution:

You can however pass the url from server side.

#### Server side:

```
function getTopUrl(){
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
}
```

#### Client side:

```
var topUrl;
function getTop(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((url)=>{topUrl=url;}).getTopUrl();
}
window.addEventListener('load', getTop);
```

#### References:

- [Where is my iframe in the published web application/sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/where-is-my-iframe-in-the-published-web-application-sidebar)
- [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access)
- [Service#getUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl())
- [google.script#run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Although I'm not sure about OP's situation, I thought that from the URL of `https://script.google.com/a/user/macros/s/A...ljhGC/dev`, OP might want to access to Web Apps with the developer mode. When `getUrl()` is used, how about adding the information to reflect the latest script?

Comment: @Tanaike The ids of `[ID]/dev` and `[ID]/exec` are quite different. Is it possible to access  the actual `dev` url?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. `{id}` of `https://script.google.com/a/{domain}/macros/s/{id}/dev` can be retrieved. In this case, it uses the method of projects.deployments.list in Apps Script API. For the response value from the method, the value of `deploymentId` in the 1st index of the property `deployments` is it. You can confirm it at [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/list).

Comment: But, I'm not sure whether OP actually needs this. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Ah yes the api. Possibly op doesn't need the dev url. Also, it's much easier to just publish the new app and get the exec url instead. Or even just copy/paste the dev url(I assume dev URL {id} doesn't change with change in source code)

Comment: @Tanaike   That was my mistake. Copied the incorrect URLs they should be `/exec` URLs.

Comment: @Sam Haberkorn Thank you for your information. Can you update your question? It will be also useful for other users.